# error : The local variable may not have been initialized (in method , code runs but variable value not get updated)

Tags: java

I am doing this program to find 2nd largest element in array, but in method an exception occurs that secondMax is not initialized....
what is wrong in this code .....

```
import java. util.*;

public class largest_inArraya {
    
    public static int second_largest(int num[]) {
        int secondMax = 0;  
        int a = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
           
              if (a > num[i]) {
                secondMax = a;
                a = num[i];
            }
        }
        return secondMax;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num[] = { 12, 25, 83, 27, 17, 51, 32, 94, 30 };
        System.out.println("second largest element is "+second_largest(num));
    }

}
```

if second.Max initialized with any valu (0 , num[0] ) it gets assign that value and returns it.....
the problem is secondMax is not get updated in loop.....
any suggestion for this....

Comment: What if you pass an empty array? What will `secondMax`'s value be? Whatever you think it should be, you should explicitly assign `secondMax` that value before doing anything else.

Comment: you can give secondMax a default value. Keep in mind that it's possible that that if statement never returns true. or the array could be empty

Comment: The code you have shown does not produce the error you have. Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have and add the complete error message you get to your question as well.